# Unable to locate the specified class while calling another controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, methods, controller

I have following code for controller Qprs

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Qprs extends CI_Controller {

    public function xyz()
    {
        //some code 
    }

}
```

below code used to call above controller from another controller

```
 $this->load->library('../controllers/Qprs');
 $this->Qprs->xyz();
```

but getting error:
**Unable to locate the specified class Qprs.php**

 How to solve such error?

Comment: You have to put this file in helper directory not a controller directory

Comment: Then how i can call another controller from one controller..

Comment: Try with lower case  $this->load->library('../controllers/qprs');
 $this->qprs->xyz();

Comment: but why you want to call another controller from one controller this is not right method

Comment: Use HMVC if you need to load controllers with in controllers  https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc normal MVC you cannot call controller with in controller, you need to add the HMVC third party

Comment: Understand the purpose of MVC, the accepted answer is a hack, not a solution.

Comment: @user7234862 then what is the solution for the problem...

Comment: For that purpose you can make a function in helper and call that function from anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple way in codeigniter to call a method of one controller to other controller

```
1. Controller A 
   class A extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function custom_a()
    {
    }
}

2. Controller B 

   class B extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function custom_b()
    {
            require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/a.php'); //include controller
            $aObj = new a();  //create object 
            $aObj->custom_a(); //call function
    }
}
```

Comment: You're Welcome.. Glad it helped

Comment: But now i'm confused with comments and your answer. Which is more safe making a function in helper or using your code?

Comment: if you want to use one function again and again..Yes you can create a helper file for that function.. and that will be a better option. infact it will make your code in well structured form.. its best for code reusability