# Which is safe, using required once or making one function in helper in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, methods, helper, require-once

I had one problem while calling controller from another controller,one of the user  of stackoverflow suggested to use require_once but another person said it's not a good idea now i'm confused, which is safe ? Using require_once or write a function in helper?
[Old question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197660/unable-to-locate-the-specified-class-while-calling-another-controller-in-codeign)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say in general that calling a controller from within another controller is not a best practice. If two controllers need to use the same logic then maybe that logic should be in a separate place. 
This can be done by creating your own library and loading it within both controllers.

Check out the link below to learn more about creating libraries in CodeIgniter.

[Creating Libraries](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Answer (score 2):

It is not so much a question of "safe" but more a matter of "convention" in the way things are done in the CodeIgniter (CI) framework. The "idea" behind a controller in CI is that on any given server request only one controller is created.

The reason using `require` to load another controller might not be "safe" is that you *might* introduce bugs that are very hard track down. There is a safer way to satisfy your needs.

In a situation where there is code that would be useful in more than one controller the best answer is probably to create a custom library that can be loaded and used were needed. A [Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) might also be the answer. IMO, libraries (classes) are the OOP way and are prefered.

The CI documentation on [Creating Libraries](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) describes how to implement custom classes that are easily used in any number of controllers.